# How do I run a replit environment on a local computer?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, replit

I developed web automation software with Selenium, Selenium configuration on replit is different with local computers.  so I want the same configuration from replit to work on the local computer too.  How to do it?  can you use docker?  will docker also save chrome for selenium?

this is the selenium environment that i use on replit
https://replit.com/@AllailQadrillah/Selenium-Environment